# Deleting symbolic links - Logics and how to

Tags: symlink

First, Happny new year all here! I'm very new to UNIX\Linux and I've mistakenly created the following Symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.confservice
```

What is the right way to **delete** it and what is the logic behind it?:

I understand I should do `unlink ***something***` command inside the folder `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/` and after I navigated to it... Therefore I ask:

1. why is the deletion action done based on the second path and not in the first one ... ?
2. Usually, is something else be written there besides the file name?

   - I'm afraid to make damage therefore I ask this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man rm`:

> The rm utility removes symbolic links, not the files referenced by the
>        links.

So just do `rm /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.confservice`.

You should learn to use `man` on any utilities before asking questions, just as general advice. It will save you time, and you'll learn a lot.

> I'm afraid to make damage therefore I ask this...

I definitely understand this feeling, I'm the same way when doing something new that I don't quite understand! The solution is to make some test files that you can play with. In fact, some commands even have a "dry-run" option that causes them to show you what steps they would perform, without actually performing them.

> Usually, is something else be written there besides the file name?

Written where --- in the symbolic link? The symbolic link literally just contains the path to the file it is pointing, in text format. You can print the contents of a symbolic link by doing `readlink my_link`.

Comment: I didn't imagined that if I'll do man rm --- It will also give me data on *deleting* symlinks... I used man a few times... It can indeed save time. Thanks for you answer, you helped me much!

Answer (score 2):

A symbolic link is usually created as (from the `man` pages):

```
ln -s target link_name
```

Here, `target` is an already existing entity (e.g., file or directory); `link_name` is the name of the (sym)link (a pointer or shortcut, if you may say) to the target file.

In your case, `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` is the target -- seems like some configuration file for PHP. Whereas `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.confservice` is the symlink you are creating.

Coming to the delete issue, one usually removes the `link_name` -- the second path provided to `ln`, but not the `target`. Doing so retains the originally linked file; it just "unlinks" the new name created. In your case, deleting `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.confservice` would retain the original configuration file `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`. If required, you can create another symlink latter pointing to the concerned target.

Finally, if you delete the `target` after creating a symlink, a "broken link" would be formed. If you do `ls -l`, the symlink would be highlighted in red. Note that deleting the target of a symlink is nothing like a prohibited action -- it is just not a typical use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the details , then follow the link in the comment , but a simple answer to your question is that a symbolic link is just like a short cut to something else. (**second path** is the symbolic link here)

So if you delete the short-cut , it doesn’t do any harm to the original thing

And you can name the short-cut anything you want.